# Importing multiple (21) tabs from excel into R: Why do I keep getting this error message "Error: unexpected '}' in " }"?

Tags: r, import

I've been trying to import data from separate sheets into R so that I can use them to calculate David's Scores for individuals.

However, for some reason, I keep getting this error message:

> ”Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"

which, after looking online, baffles me!

Also, it gives an X next to the row number saying there is an unmatched opening bracket '(', but I cannot find any unmatched open brackets anywhere?

Below is my code:

```
read_excel_allsheets <- function("C:/Users/James/Desktop/Animal Behaviour Project/Interaction Data/Dominance Only Interaction Data Final.xlsx" ) {
  Sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets("C:/Users/James/Desktop/Animal Behaviour Project/Interaction Data/Dominance Only Interaction Data Final.xlsx")
  Groups <- lapply(Sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel("C:/Users/James/Desktop/Animal Behaviour Project/Interaction Data/Dominance Only Interaction Data Final.xlsx", sheet = X))
  names(Groups) <- Sheets 
}
```

Comment: Brackets look matched to me. That said, unless you put a `Groups` or `return(Groups)` at the end of your function, the returned value will just be what's on the last line: the names in `Sheets`, not the read-in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use a string as a parameter in the function.  I would suggest something like this instead:

```
read_excel_allsheets <- function(file_name = "C:/Users/James/Desktop/Animal Behaviour Project/Interaction Data/Dominance Only Interaction Data Final.xlsx" ) {
  Sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(file_name)
  Groups <-    lapply(Sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(file_name, sheet = X))
  names(Groups) <- Sheets 
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much! You've saved me a frustrating evening!